# Is it possible to use Snowflake user and named stages for long term data file storage?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Instead of creating our own S3 bucket, I'm wondering if I can just leverage user and named stages as ways to store data files (that may not be loaded into tables).  Or are files in these stages automatically purged by Snowflake at times?

Comment: What data are you going to put into a named/user stage that you wouldn't put into a table?

Comment: It's some data I might not want to formalize into a table yet but looking for a cloud solution option when I don't have access to something like an S3 bucket.  That's why I was eyeing a Snowflake user stage as an option.

Comment: Then yes you could but I would use an s3 bucket. It's going to cost you the same amount either way.

Answer (score 1):

Internal Stages are not managed by Users, so anything you upload into Internal Stages if you want to query has to be copied into the tables eventually.

If you are using PUT command, you can list the files and then use copy into tables command.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html

Using PUT operation into Internal Stages will incur Storage Charges as applicable.

Comment: What is meant by "purges into tables eventually"?  If a user puts a file to their user internal stage, doesn't it stay there until you run a COPY INTO command and get it loaded?

Comment: It seems like COPY INTO does not automatically purge the original file by default? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Comment: Also, you can query data in Snowflake that is still in files in a stage similar to AWS Athena, I think.  Likely not in an optimized format as if it were in a table, but it's still doable.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html